# Restrict values of C# command-line-parser options to Integers

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-parser

I am currently working on a console app which uses this  [command line parser library](https://commandline.codeplex.com/).
Some of my option values should be Integers. So I was wondering if there is a way to specify these options in such a way that they only accept values of type `int`.

I already read through the documentary of the library but didn't find such functionality. But maybe I missed something.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all you have to do is declare the return type as an int. This example is in the documentation:

```
[Option("l", "length", HelpText = "The maximum number of bytes to process.")]
  public int MaximumLength { get; set; };
// ...
}

The following will be accepted.
  GuideApp --length=99
  GuideApp -l12345
  GuideApp -l 555
The following will be rejected.
  GuideApp --length=a-string
  GuideApp -lsome_text
  GuideApp -l text.again
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for :)